# In what cases should you install eslint globally?

Tags: javascript, eslint, sublimetext4

I have 3 projects each in their own repository and folder.  I use sublime to do my linting from the GUI.  Sometimes if I want to auto fix files I will go to the command line and run `eslint . --fix`

My configurations are getting a bit complicated as I have had to install multiple packages for sublime, I've had to setup a configuration file in sublime for eslint, and I have had to setup the configuration file for eslint itself.

And finally, I am trying to use the babel parser instead of the default pareser but am not able to get it to work.  Everything else seems to work fine.

So I am trying to make sure I understand how all these pieces work together before I troubleshoot further.

Currently I have node and nodemon installed globally.  But it also makes sense to install eslint, and associated packages globally as well.

I mean in general I don't understand why you would want different projects to have different styles so I don't understand why the directions suggest you install locally for each project.

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started

In particular

> It is also possible to install ESLint globally rather than locally
> (using npm install eslint --global). However, this is not recommended,
> and any plugins or shareable configs that you use must be installed
> locally in either case.

Why is this so?

Can I setup just one of my folders correctly, i.e. locally, and have sublime know how to line my other two folders/projects?

Seems like more complexity is added by requiring local installation of plugins.  Are these directions valid and if so why are there many places doing global installs?  For example [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227262/how-to-install-eslint-globally).

I'm trying to make my configuration life easier not harder.

**Sublime ESLint Config File**

```
{
  "node_path": "/usr/local/bin",
  "node_modules_path": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules",
  "config_file": "/Users/c/top/ll/config/.eslintrc"
}
```

**.eslintrc File**

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": "error",
    "indent": ["error", 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
    "eqeqeq": ["error", "always"],
    "max-depth": ["error", 5],
    "space-before-function-paren": ["error", "never"],
    "template-curly-spacing": ["error", "always"],
    "quotes": ["error", "single", { "allowTemplateLiterals": true }],
    "curly": "error",
    "brace-style": ["error", "1tbs"],
    "space-before-blocks": "error"
  }
}
```

Comment: There are some good explanation in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227262/how-to-install-eslint-globally

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install ESlint globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227262/how-to-install-eslint-globally)

Comment: @David - no I posted that link in my question, Please read the question.

Answer (score 0):

ESLint is intended to be used in a project-basis. If you want to have the same configurations, you need to configure your IDE to apply your ESlint settings on all projects.

You can check for [SublimeLinter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/stable/) and configure your ESLint settings for all your projects